# Issue with auto-hide after full screen videos in Firefox

Tags: firefox, panel, dock

I'm assuming there is a setting that is causing the issue.

The issue is that after I watch a video on YouTube, and open it full screen (via hitting "F" or the spot in the bottom right of the video).

Once I exit full screen of the video (not full screen of Firefox by hitting F11 I believe it is), the Dock (Ubuntu installs with it at the left, but I have it at the bottom) will attempt to come up when I go to the bottom where I have it, but after 5 or 6 times of quickly going up and down, it refuses to come up as usual.

The solution I have at present is to close Firefox and reopen the browser. I also have the panel (that is typically at the top) to the dock as well, with Arc menu.

Is there a setting I am missing or that is conflicting and causing this issue?

[image: Image of dock/panel for clarification]

Just to clarify, I am using Ubuntu with Gnome, 20.04LTS, Firefox 79.0 for Ubuntu canonical 1.0.